# An interesting doubly infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0<\mu<1$ and $\alpha:=1-\mu^2$. Consider the function 
$$f(x):=x\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\mu^{4k}e^{-\alpha\mu^{4k}x}-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\mu^{4k}e^{-\alpha\mu^{4k}/x},$$
defined for all $x>0$. Three properties are easy to check: $f(\mu^{2n})=0$ for every integer $n$, $f(x)=-f(1/x)$, $f(x)$ vanishes at $x=\mu^2$ and $x=1$ and $f(x)=f(\mu^4x)$.

I want to show that $f(x)<0$ for $\mu^2<x<1$, but I have not been able to prove it. Has anybody seen anything like this?

Comment: Did you finish what you intended to write? I don't see a question.

Comment: @Greg: there was some error/bug with the LaTeX formatting. I've cleaned it up.

Comment: Take a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61350/determining-the-asymptotic-behavior-of-a-series 
before getting too deeply involved 

Comment: Where does this arise?  The desired inequality fails for many choices of $\mu$, such as $\mu=1/4$ as detailed in my answer below; but perhaps the source of the problem might point to an inequality that does hold (or at least comes closer...) and is still tractable by the same method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen sums like this, and they can get quite amusing, e.g. the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$ as a periodic function of $\log(x)$ involve values of the Gamma function at complex arguments (see below); but it seems that this is overkill for the question at hand: there are several ranges of $\mu$ for which $f(\mu) > 0$, e.g. $\mu = 1/4$ works, giving $f(1/4) = 0.0892157+ > 0$.  Are you sure this is what you meant?

If I computed everything correctly (and **gp** corroborates numerically), the following sine-Fourier expansion holds: write $\mu = \exp(-\lambda)$ and $x = \mu^t = \exp(-\lambda t)$; then
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phantom. c_n \sin \frac{\pi n t}{2}
$$
where
$$
c_n = \frac1\lambda \mathop{\rm Im} \left(
\Gamma\bigl(1 + \frac{\pi i n}{2\lambda}\bigr) \Bigl/ \alpha^{1 + \frac{\pi i n}{2\lambda}}
\right).
$$
This does not depend on the choice $\alpha = 1 - \mu^2$.

P.S. See
[this Mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11255/80730#80730)
where such a sum (and its Fourier expansion with complex-Gamma coefficients) arises naturally.

Comment: Noam, take a look at the edit history of the OP's other question as well. In short, others do all the work. 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much, you're right, it is not true for $\mu=1/4$, meaning that in general the real zeros of the function $f(x)$ are not just $\mu^{2n}$, $n$ an integer. I thought that this perhaps was the case, implying what I wanted to prove. I'll explain more:

Define $$\chi_q(t):=t^2\int_0^\infty \mu^{-4\langle\log_{\mu^4}(s)+q\rangle }s e^{-(\mu^{-1}-\mu) ts}ds ,\quad \Re(t)>0$$ where $\mu$ and $q$ are constants with $0<\mu<1$, $0\leq q < 1$, and $\langle x\rangle$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

The function I am looking at originally is
$$g_q(t)=\chi_q(t)-\chi_q(\mu^2/t),\quad \Re(t)>0.$$ This functions satisfies $g_q(\mu^4t)=g_q(t)$.
What I thought would be the case is that $g_q(t)$ has $\mu$ as its only zero in the region $\Re(t)>\mu^2R/2$, $|t-1/R|<1/R$. Here $R=\mu^{-1}+\mu$. This region is its own reflection about the circle of radius $\mu$, and the intersection of this region with the real axis is the interval $(\mu^2R/2, 2/R)$.

The function $s\mu^{-4\langle\log_{\mu^4}(s)+q\rangle }$ is a step function, and by integrating we can write $g_q(t)$ as the doubly infinite series (up to a multiplicative constant):$$t\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\mu^{4(k-q)}e^{-(\mu^{-1}-\mu)\mu^{4(k-q)}t}-\frac{\mu^2}{t}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\mu^{4(k-q)}e^{-(\mu^{-1}-\mu)\mu^{4(k-q)}(\mu^2/t)}$$

For $q=0$, this is essentially the function in the original question since $f(x)=\mu^{-1} g_0(\mu x)$.

However, computational experiments with Mathematica indicate that for small values of $\mu$, g_0(t) has at least three real zeros in the interval $(\mu^2R/2, 2/R)$, and this seems to be the case as well for $\mu=1/5$ and $q=1/1000$, which disproves my conjecture. Below is the Mathematica code. Here m is $\mu$, and I truncate the series at $k=M$.

M = 300;

m = 1/5;

q = 0;

N[m]

R = m + 1/m;

g[x_] := x*(Sum[
       m^(4*(k - q))*Exp[-(1/m - m)* m^(4*(k - q))*x], {k, 0, M}] + 
      Sum[m^(4*(-k - q))*Exp[-(1/m - m)* m^(4*(-k - q))*(m^2/x)], {k, 
        1, M}]) - (m^2/
      x)*(Sum[m^(4*(k - q))*Exp[-(1/m - m)*m^(4*(k - q))*(m^2/x)], {k,
         0, M}] + 
      Sum[m^(4*(-k - q))*Exp[-(1/m - m)* m^(4*(-k - q))*(m^2/x)], {k, 
        1, M}]);

Plot[g[x], {x, m^2*R/2, 2/R}, PlotRange -> All]

Comment: This should be merged with the question, not added as an answer.